# How to retrieve stock price for specific date and tickers?

Tags: r, quantmod

I have a table

```
Ticker.    Date
AAPL.      1/1/2020
AAPL.      1/2/2020
KO.        1/1/2020
KO.        1/20/2020
```

I want to add two more columns to the same table with closing and adjusted price to give

```
Ticker.  Date.            Adj_Price.    Closing_Price
AAPL.      1/1/2020.          234           235
AAPL.      1/2/2020.          245           249
KO.        1/1/2020            30            32
KO.        1/20/2020           33            44
```

I think we can do this using quant mod library

Comment: Maybe read the manuals, then come back with more specific questions?

Comment: Have a look at `tidyquant::tq_get`.

Comment: If Fund is the dataset name, then does it work? `Fund$adjClose <- tidyquant::tq_get(Fund$Ticker Symbol,get = "stock.prices", from = Fund$Data Date, to = Fund$Data Date)`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
> tickers = c('AAPL', 'KO')
> portfolio <- NULL
> for(t in tickers){
+   portfolio <- cbind(portfolio, getSymbols(t, from = '2020-01-01', to = '2020-01-21', auto.assign = 0)[,c(4,6)])
+ }
> portfolio
           AAPL.Close AAPL.Adjusted KO.Close KO.Adjusted
2020-01-02    75.0875      74.57304    54.99    53.58738
2020-01-03    74.3575      73.84803    54.69    53.29503
2020-01-06    74.9500      74.43647    54.67    53.27554
2020-01-07    74.5975      74.08639    54.25    52.86625
2020-01-08    75.7975      75.27816    54.35    52.96370
2020-01-09    77.4075      76.87714    55.34    53.92844
2020-01-10    77.5825      77.05093    55.53    54.11360
2020-01-13    79.2400      78.69707    56.13    54.69830
2020-01-14    78.1700      77.63441    56.00    54.57161
2020-01-15    77.8350      77.30170    56.70    55.25376
2020-01-16    78.8100      78.27002    56.82    55.37069
2020-01-17    79.6825      79.13655    56.94    55.48764
> portfolio[index(portfolio) %in% as.Date(c('2020-01-15','2020-01-16'))]
           AAPL.Close AAPL.Adjusted KO.Close KO.Adjusted
2020-01-15     77.835      77.30170    56.70    55.25376
2020-01-16     78.810      78.27002    56.82    55.37069
>
```

You can subset using any date you want.

Comment: Thanks Karthik. No, it doesn't because its a huge dataset, and dates can not be entered manually

Comment: Is there a logic in retrieving, as in, you'd take only Monday's prices or specific gap between two days?

Comment: Just the closing price of that day and adjusted closing price for the day. I'm a novice to programming, and used this `Fund$adjClose <- tidyquant::tq_get(Fund$Ticker Symbol,get = "stock.prices", from = Fund$Data Date, to = Fund$Data Date)`; but it doesn't seem working. Don't know why.

Comment: Usually the prices taken for a date range, not sure why you want to select only few days in between at random?

Comment: So here is the example why, its a fundamental dataset with revenue, profit etc., along with the date of financial result. I am looking to add the closing price as of the sate of financial result.

Comment: And I am not looking for prices between two dates, just looking for the price on that specific date

Comment: Do you have a list of dates that's you'd be retrieving or just one date at a time? If it's the latter, then you can use my code, but if it's a list, can you share it, we can try to fetch based on that list at one go?

Comment: As I told its a huge dataset, with variables: Ticker, Date, Revenue, Profit etc... The dates goes back as far as 1950. Am looking to add a stock price column to that table, by retrieving ticker and date for each row